# Does JSSE implement a fallback if the server does not support the used protocol?

Tags: java, ssl, fallback, jsse

I'm just gathering some information about `SSL/TSL` within java, as we are using netty without even knowing what `TLS` protocol we are using currently. Our application runs on Java7, so a `SSLSocket` will run with `TLS1` by default and `SSL3` is not even activated. That I know now.

Assuming my client runs on Java8 (that uses by default TLS1.2) the target server only supports `TLS1.1`, is `JSSE` now using an automatic fallback routing to negotiate a connection with `TLS1.1`? Or do I have to implement this specifically? If yes, where would I have to do that?

I couldn't find a clear point for that in the `JSSE` documentation.

Comment: [JSSE protocols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSE_Protocols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is JSSE now using an automatic fallback ...?

It doesn't have to.

A TLS client sends the highest version of the TLS protocol it can support. The server replies with the TLS version it wants to use, which is the lower of the highest version the server supports and the version sent by the client. If the client supports that version, the handshake proceeds. So it is actually the *server* that does the fallback.

This is all specified in [RFC 2246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt). It is not peculiar to Java.